# In R: How do I calculate the averages within a vector over different elements specified by another vector?

Tags: r, vector, sum, average, calculation

Let's say we have 2 vectors:

```
x <- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,5,5)
y <- c(40,228,280,252,211,226,235,240,179,175,197,203,227,258,240)
```

Now I want to sum the elements in y corresponding to the value in x and divide them by the number of occurences in x to store it accordingly:

`40, 239.4, 213.25, 201, 249`

For example `(228 + 280 + 252 + 211 + 226)/5 = 239.4`

I'd be thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  `base R` solution could help you with `tapply()`:

```
tapply(y,x, mean)
```

Output:

```
   1      2      3      4      5 
 40.00 239.40 213.25 201.00 249.00
```

If you want to save the results in another vector you could use `z <- as.vector(tapply(y,  x, mean))`